# Post call on button click to download excel report

Tags: java, angular, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to download excel file giving `POST` call on button click from angular js. 
My java controller returns void .

service to write in excel file:

```
response.setContentType("application/ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment filename=\"" + fileName + ".xls"+ "\"");
workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
```

response is of type `HttpServletResponse`.

How do i write method in `Angular` to download file??

Comment: we want to make a post call not a href

Answer (score 1):

To download File from server.

Call function on button click.

```
 downloadFile():void
  {
    this.getFiles("http://localhost:80080/api/demo/GetTestFile")
    .subscribe(fileData => 
      {
      let b:any = new Blob([fileData], { type: 'application/zip' });
      var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(b);
        window.open(url);
      }
    );
  }

  public getFiles(path: string):Observable<any>{
    let requestOption = new RequestOptions({responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob});
    return this.http.get(filePath, requestOption)
        .map((response: Response) => <Blob>response.blob())  ;
  }
```

Comment: we are using angular js

Comment: This is for angular 2+.

Comment: Any idea how to do it in angularjs?